# Using a TabBar controller, reloading/reallocating views

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, reload

Is there away that each time you switch to a view in a tabBar controller it reloads it the same way it would the first time it was loaded/allocated?

Answer (score 0):

In your UITabBarControllerDelegate, you can reset the appropriate views `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` and/or `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:`.

Comment: How would you "reset" the views?

Answer (score 0):

My apologizes, this was a fairly simple solution:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

Unless some guru thinks this is poor execution?

Comment: I've thought about doing this as well. But I am concerned that reloading the table will upset the selected cells.I think I just have to try it.